# How to reference assembly 'System.Threading,

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code as in below in my application, at first it could not compile, it showed error message as

> "The type 'Task' exists in both 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' "

so I removed the `"System.Threading"` I installed via Nuget, then the new error message is as:

> CS0012: The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

pointing the error at the following line in the code below

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> t =  client.PostAsync("https://Mypay.com/api/", content);
```

This is the code as I used it:

```
   var client = new HttpClient();
   var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
   values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task", task));
   values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("merchant", merchant_id));
   values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ref", id));
   // include other fields
   var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);


   Task<HttpResponseMessage> t =  client.PostAsync("https://Mypay.com/api/", content);
   t.Wait();
   var response = t.Result;
```

So how do I reference the assembly, or correct the error?

Comment: It is not a good idea to put actual URLs in support forums, as it may call for unwarranted access an misuse.

Comment: What's your target framework / .NET version?

Comment: the target framework is 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the class `Task` was defined in more than one references. So you can specify the one with respect to their namespace. for this you have to use Fully Qualified name like this :

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseMEssage =  client.PostAsync("https://voguepay.com/api/", content);
```

> A [fully qualified name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx) consists of an assembly name
>   specification, a namespace specification, and a type name. Type name
>   specifications are used by methods such as Type.GetType,
>   Module.GetType, ModuleBuilder.GetType, and Assembly.GetType.

Comment: I did as you said and I got this error: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Task' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I updated it, it was corrected, but I still get the former Error message: CS0012: The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the reference to `System.Runtime`, and recompile again.

You can read more about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869730/problems-with-references-to-tpl-dataflow-and-tpl-in-vs-2012-rc).

Comment: My problem is getting hold of NuGet Package Explorer

Comment: I manage to get NuGet Package Explorer, I tried to follow your instruction in your post, but the Explorer did not show System.Runtime in the Framework Assembly Reference for System.Threading.